# Cross browser, cross platform bookmark sync?

Tags: synchronization, bookmarks, xmarks

Now that xmarks is closing (See blog: http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1886 ),
I am looking for a bookmark sync solution that has the following features:

- "Secure", i.e. unauthorized users should not have access to my bookmarks
- Works across multiple browsres (Firefox, IE, Chrome for sure; Safari and others optional)
- Works Across multiple platforms (Windows XP/Vista/7, Linux; Optionally, android/iphone)

I am aware of the following solutions, but they each have limitations:

- [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/): Does not work with IE/Chrome
- [Chrome Bookmark Sync](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139): Does not work with IE/Firefox
- [Zinkmo](http://www.zinkmo.com/): Claims to work with IE and Firefox, but I find very few users using it. Anybody using it here?
- [Windows Live Essentials](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-devices-and-sync-program-settings-ui): Does not work with Chrome/Firefox

Yes, I am aware I can [setup my own private xmarks server](http://lifehacker.com/5651152/how-to-continue-syncing-bookmarks-with-xmarks-on-your-own-server), but I don't want the headache of having to maintain my own server.

This question technically belongs in both superuser.com (because it is software that runs on your PC) as well as webapps.stackexchange.com (because the backend is a webapp), and I chose to post it here because I think this is really a better fit.

Comment: Does it have to use the browser's native bookmark interface, or is a site such as http://start.io good enough?

Comment: Yes, has to use browser's "native" bookmark interface.

Comment: w00t! xMarks is still around

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about browser data syncing, not a web app.

Answer (score 3):

Have you ever used [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com/)? It's a web app with bookmarklets that work in Safari, Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera. You can make any bookmark "private" so that it is not available publicly. Additionally, your bookmarks are taggable, so you are not limited to a strictly hierarchical folder structure.

Comment: And exactly how would you sync the browser's bookmarks across multiple platforms/machines with Delicious?

Comment: most major browsers have delicious plugins...

Comment: @joyjit: your boorkmarks live on the delicious service in the cloud. Your browser downloads your delicious bookmarks from the service, and creates them as local bookmarks in your browser. The plugins would handle the syncing across all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xmark plugin on Safari & Chrome.
It's available for Firefox as well.
iPhone app is there too.
You can also check your bookmarks by internet site.
Sync with Delicious...

I think Xmark is the best cross-platform bookmark sync in the marker out there.

Grab it...it's free.

Answer (score 0):

LifeHacker also did a [post highlighting the following 5 bookmark management tools](http://lifehacker.com/5540019/five-best-bookmark-management-tools).

1. FireFox Sync (at the time, Weave)
2. XMarks
3. Diigo
4. Delicious
5. Google Bookmarks